# dynamical system modified by PD matrix

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Assume we have a dynamical system, i.e an ODE of the form
$$
\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=g(\vec{x})
$$
which we know how to solve.
Now consider a modified ODE
$$
\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}=\hat{A}g(\vec{x})
$$
with $\hat{A}$ being a positive definite matrix constant in time with known eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Can we learn something about the solution of the modified ODE from our knowledge of the solution of the original one? Maybe an easier way to numerically find the solution or proving any convergence properties?

Comment: Except for stationary points, there is probably not much to say in this generality. Note, that the equation $\dot y(t) = A g(A^{-1} y(t))$ would be just a change of basis for the first equation and solutions could be mapped one-to-one from either to the other.